# M2.2.5 : Can someone explain the role / functionality of the various tables used by the indexing process?

Tags: magento2, indexing, indexer

I've read [the documentation about indexing in Magento 2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html), but it's very much on the surface. What I am wondering is how do the internals of the indexing mechanism work. Can somebody explain this to me? If I look for example at the Category/Product relation I can determine the following:

The following tables are involved in my setup:

- `catalog_category_product`
- `catalog_category_product_cl`
- `catalog_category_product_index`
- `catalog_category_product_index_replica`
- `catalog_category_product_index_store1`
- `catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica`
- `catalog_category_product_index_store2`
- `catalog_category_product_index_store2_replica`
- `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`

So far, I understand the following about the indexing process:

- Category/Product relations are stored in `catalog_category_product`.
- Whenever the is a change to this relation, a new version is pushed to the changelog (`catalog_category_product_cl`) to be picked up by the Materialized View implementation by comparing versions in the `mview_state`-table.
- `catalog_category_product_index_tmp` is populated during indexing and swapped at the end the process with `catalog_category_product_index`.

But here are my questions I still have left:

- What is the purpose of the `_replica`-table?
- Why are there indexes per store even though the `catalog_category_product_index` has a `store_id`-table?
- Not sure if this is a bug, but why are there differences between the products in `catalog_category_product_index::store_id=1` and `catalog_category_product_index_store1`? To clarify: In `catalog_category_product_index` I have a product that is assigned to 6 category ID's, whereas the same product in the dedicated `_store1`-index is only assigned to 4 category ID's. Could be a bug though.

Any help/explanation from core Magento developers or more experienced Magento developers is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`catalog_category_product_index_tmp` is used to store  intermediate data for a batch product in the process of indexation

`*_replica` tables are used for full indexation process to not affect the Store Front in process of indexation

`*_store*` tables added in 2.2.5 to split index per store and table `catalog_category_product_index` become outdated

Comment: So if I understand correctly: if I'm on Magento 2.2.5 the `catalog_category_product_index` is no longer required? Can I just drop this table? Why doesn't the upgrade script of `Magento_Catalog` does this for me? I love it how Magento manages to introduce such major changes in a simple "patch" release ... :-/

Comment: Yes, you can delete catalog_category_product_index. On code level, queries to catalog_category_product_index will be directed to catalog_category_product_index_store* based on current store, so there no BC changes